# GWT2.2 java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for a class (did you forget to inherit a required module?)

Tags: gwt, binding, deferred

I'm using gwt 2.2, and encountered with the below exception:
18:43:48.896 [ERROR] [dms] Failed to create an instance of 'package.DMS' via deferred binding

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'package.client.FileServiceAsync' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at person.tanjinfu.dms.client.DMS.&lt;init&gt;(DMS.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at person.tanjinfu.dms.client.DMS.&lt;init&gt;(DMS.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is there anybody can help me?

Comment: Please post your .gwt.xml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use GWT.create() on the synchronous interface like `GWT.create(FileService.class)`. Your exception looks like, you are creating a non-async interface. GWT returns an instance that implements your Async interface even though you pass in the Sync interface while creating.

Also make sure that your sync interface extends the RemoteService interface.

Comment: thanks Zasz, I have figured out the reason. My statement is GWT.create(FileServiceAsync.class) instead of FileSercice.class, which caused the exception.

Comment: Shouldnt you mark the answer as Right then, look for the green Tick mark by the side of the answer :)